How to run Stable Diffusion 3.5 Large on 4090?
I have 4090 and this code:
login(HF_TOKEN)
        self.pipe = StableDiffusion3Pipeline.from_pretrained("stabilityai/stable-diffusion-3.5-large", torch_dtype=torch.bfloat16)

self.pipe = self.pipe.to("cuda")

This fails to load to vram due to oom.
What is the correct way to run it?
Tried using other floats but did not work
